Diplaying extreme intervals on a Dash-Plotly App
This is my app:
def plot_data(dataframe):
    # Initialize the Dash app
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    # Define the layout of the app
    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
        html.P("Starting point of the interval:"),
        dcc.Slider(id="start-slider", min=1, max=len(dataframe) - 1, value=1, step=22),
        html.P("Maximum lag:"),
        dcc.Slider(id="lag-slider", min=1, max=len(dataframe), value=len(dataframe), step=22),
    ])
    
    @app.callback(
        Output("graph", "figure"),
        [Input("start-slider", "value"),
         Input("lag-slider", "value")]
    )
    def update_plot(start, lag):
        # Slice the data based on the selected interval
        selected_data = dataframe.iloc[start-1:start+lag-1]
        

        # Create trace for 'Cento' column
        trace_cento = go.Scatter(x=selected_data['Date'], y=selected_data['Cento'], mode='lines', name='Seasonality')

        # Create layout
        layout = go.Layout(
            title=f"<b>Copper Seasonality</b><br>",
            titlefont=dict(size=16, color='black', family='Arial'),
            yaxis=dict(title='Performance'),
            showlegend=True,
            title_x=0.5
        )

        # Create figure with trace and layout
        fig = go.Figure(data=trace_cento, layout=layout)

        return fig

    # Run the app
    app.run_server()



plot_data(mean_values)

However, what I want is that when I select the interval within the graph, like this:

it prints me out the date of the BEGINNING of the selected interval and the date of END of the interval, so in this case would be like: 16 April and 14 June. I tried to add another callback, but I couldn't figure it out.
